# Why does this sqlsrv query with parameters not work?

Tags: php, sql, sqlsrv

I have the following function in my code.

```
private function getFormsOfWords($search){

    $query = "SELECT display_term, source_term, occurrence FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, ?)', 2057, 0, 0)";

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($this->db, $query, array($search));

    if( $stmt === false ) {
        file_put_contents(LOG_DIR.'/search.txt', print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true), FILE_APPEND);
        die();
    }
    $highlight_words = array();
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        $highlight_words[] = $row['display_term'];
    }

    return $highlight_words;
}
```

The problem is that when I get to the sqlsrv_fetch_array part, I get no results.

The debugger is showing that the $search variable is populated and the sqlsrv_fetch_array line does get reached.

All of the other queries that I've done in the exact same way have successfully produced results after executing sqlsrv_fetch_array.

I've tested the $highlight_words_SQL query in the database itself with the parameter manually substituted, and it works fine. The main difference there is the parameter needs quotes around it to work when executing manually. I'm assuming that the param argument of sqlsrv_query gets processed in a way that will handle this requirement, but I did also try the following query with the same blank result:

```
$query = "SELECT display_term, source_term, occurrence FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, \"?\")', 2057, 0, 0)";
```

The "search.txt" error log is not showing anything, and neither do any other apache or php logs.

Any idea what's causing this?

EDIT:

I've tried the following permutations as well:

```
$query = "SELECT display_term, source_term, occurrence 
            FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,' + ? + ')', 2057, 0, 0)";
//Syntax error near 'initialized' in the full-text search condition 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,security initialized)'.

$query = "SELECT display_term, source_term, occurrence 
            FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,' + \"?\" + ')', 2057, 0, 0)";
//Invalid column name '?'

$query = "SELECT display_term, source_term, occurrence 
            FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,\'' + \"?\" + '\')', 2057, 0, 0)";
//Incorrect syntax near '\'.
```

This:

```
SELECT display_term, source_term, occurrence 
  FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, '+'"security initialized"'+')', 2057, 0, 0)
```

or this:

```
SELECT display_term, source_term, occurrence 
  FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "security initialized")', 2057, 0, 0)
```

are the goals, since they are the queries that work in SSMS.

Comment: Parameters aren't expanded inside quoted strings.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters aren't replaced inside quoted strings in the query. You need to build the string using concatenation.

```
$query = "SELECT display_term, source_term, occurrence 
            FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,' + ? + ')', 2057, 0, 0)";
```

Comment: I get the following when I try that query: Syntax error near 'initialized' in the full-text search condition 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,security initialized)'.

Answer (score 0):

This version of the query worked:

```
$query = "SELECT display_term, source_term, occurrence 
            FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,\"' + ? + '\")', 2057, 0, 0)";
```